# Visual Basic & HTML Agility Pack

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to pull the title of page from yahoo

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=plug

I ask user for Symbol is creates the url: http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=plug

The program works great when I load a local .html of the same page...

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim symbol As String, htmldoc As New HtmlDocument
    symbol = TextBox3.Text
    htmldoc.Load("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=plug")
    Dim items = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//head/title").Select(Function(node) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(node.InnerText, node.InnerText))

    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In items
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value)
    Next

End Sub
```

Anyone have any idea on how I could get this work? I eventually want to pull stock prices etc...

I'm also down for learning an easier way to do what I am trying to accomplish. Instead of using KeyValuePair etc... Just something I finally got to work on another SO question.

Thanks.

Comment: Also whoever voted this down I have been researching this for the past week, and I finally got this far!

Comment: You generally should state what exactly the problem is and the errors you receive. You basically asked, "here's my code, how do I make this work?"

Answer (score 3):

When pulling a web url, you should be using the `HtmlWeb` class to load the documents.  The `HtmlDocument.Load` method can only read from local files (or streams).  You're probably seeing an error along the lines of "cannot read from url" or "url not supported".

```
Dim url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=plug"
Dim web = new HtmlWeb
Dim doc = web.Load(url)
Dim titleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/title")
Dim title As String
If titleNode IsNot Nothing Then
    title = titleNode.InnerText
End If
```